# Delete UITableViewCell row with NSMutableArray throws exception

Tags: swift, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults

I have a tableview and the data inside each cell is an NSMutableArray. I want to delete a row of the tableview each time I swipe left and press the delete button. However it is difficult with an NSMutableArray. I get a Sigabrt everytime I input the code `toDoItems.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)`.

The error I get is

> Terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'

Any help on this problem?

Here is code relating to the problem.

ViewDidLoad code containing toDoItems:

```
let userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        let itemListFromUserDefaults:NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as? NSMutableArray

        if ((itemListFromUserDefaults) != nil){
            toDoItems = itemListFromUserDefaults!
        }
```

My NSMutableArray variable

```
var toDoItems:NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()
```

My commitEditingStyle function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){

    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete){


        //This code gives me the error and Sigabrt
        toDoItems.removeObjectAtIndex(indexPath.row)



        tbl?.reloadData();


    }
```

My numberOfRowsInSection function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{


        return toDoItems.count
    }
```

My cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->
    UITableViewCell{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TableView

            let toDoItem:NSDictionary = toDoItems.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! NSDictionary
            cell.lbl.text = toDoItem.objectForKey("itemTitel") as? String

            return cell



}
```

Here is the error

MyPlanner[12373:461118] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109df3d85 **exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000109867deb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109df3cbd +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109de9dae -[__NSCFArray removeObjectAtIndex:] + 94
    4   MyPlanner                           0x0000000109210c53 _TTSf4dg_n_g_n___TFC9MyPlanner14ViewController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView18commitEditingStyleOSC27UITableViewCellEditingStyle17forRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 131
    5   MyPlanner                           0x000000010920fc3d _TToFC9MyPlanner14ViewController9tableViewfTCSo11UITableView18commitEditingStyleOSC27UITableViewCellEditingStyle17forRowAtIndexPathCSo11NSIndexPath_T_ + 61
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010ac124c0 -[UITableView animateDeletionOfRowWithCell:] + 205
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010abe7a3e __52-[UITableView _swipeActionButtonsForRowAtIndexPath:]_block_invoke + 80
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010ac13eaa -[UITableView _actionButton:pushedInCell:] + 172
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010ae3aae6 -[UITableViewCell _actionButtonPushed:] + 82
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010aab4a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010ac27e67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010ac28143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010ac27263 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010af9cc52 _UIGestureRecognizerUpdate + 10279
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010ab2748e -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 1137
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010ab286c4 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 849
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010aad3dc6 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010aaad553 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6660
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d19301 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d0f22c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d0e6e3 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109d0e0f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010ec78ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010aab2f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
    25  MyPlanner                           0x00000001092134fd main + 125
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010d43d92d start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)

Here is the code where I put in the information(add items) in toDoItems.

```
@IBAction func ClickedforSelection(sender: AnyObject) {

    if delegate != nil {
        let information : NSString = txt1.text!

        delegate!.userDidEntredInformation(information)

    }

    let userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var itemList:NSMutableArray? = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as? NSMutableArray

    let dataSet:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
    dataSet.setObject(txt.text!, forKey: "itemTitel")


    if ((itemList) != nil){ // data already available
        let newMutableList:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();

        for dict:AnyObject in itemList!{
            newMutableList.addObject(dict as! NSDictionary)
        }

        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("itemList")
        newMutableList.addObject(dataSet)
        userDefaults.setObject(newMutableList, forKey: "itemList")


    }else{ // This is the first todo item in the list
        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("itemList")
        itemList = NSMutableArray()
        itemList!.addObject(dataSet)
        userDefaults.setObject(itemList, forKey: "itemList")
    }

    userDefaults.synchronize()
```

Comment: What is the text associated with the NSException?  Why does your delete code not handle the case where the information is coming from the `filteredAppleProducts` array?

Comment: Please check the edit I created with the full error

Comment: @Paulw11 I took out filteredAppleProducts however it still is not working

Comment: Are there any line of code that you assign toDoItems as an normal array (not mutable)? Please show the code you init the toDoItems.

Comment: @SonLe I don't have any other codes that contain toDoItems, and where I init toDoItems is the first line of code shown var toDoItems: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

Comment: @SonLe And I haven't stored any other data for toDoItems as a normal array.

Comment: How do you add Items into toDoItems?

Comment: @SonLe That is located in another viewcontroller, where I add my own information, and that information is then sent to the main viewcontroller, I posted the code, it is the last thing.

Comment: You should try something like this in swift: [toDoItems addObjectsFromArray:itemListFromUserDefaults].

Comment: @SonLe where would I put that line of code?

Comment: Replace this line in your code: toDoItems = itemListFromUserDefaults!. similar to Paulw11 answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` `objectForKey` will always return immutable objects.  Simply down casting it won't make it mutable.  You need to create a mutable array from the immutable array that is returned:

```
let userDefaults:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

if let itemListFromUserDefaults = userDefaults.objectForKey("itemList") as? NSArray
    toDoItems = itemListFromUserDefaults.mutableCopy()
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me where I should put that line of code.

Comment: Wherever you have the code above that is retrieving the array from `NSUserDefaults`; `viewDidLoad`

Comment: Also, since you are initialising `toDoItems` with an empty `NSMutableArray` there is no need to make it an implicitly unwrapped optional; you don't need the `:NSMutableArray!`

Comment: there is one more problem, when I kill the app and run it again, the cells that I had deleted are still showing, where I want them to just be deleted and not showing.

Comment: You need to write the array back to user defaults after you change it

Comment: Somewhere in your code you must have `userDefaults.setObject(toDoList,forKey:"itemList")` - You need to do this after you delete something from the array, otherwise the array in NSUserDefaults is still the old one and when you reload it, the deleted item will come back